# Azure Notification Hub like simple sender

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have some question about Azure notification hub.

1. It is possible to send push message to gcm or apns without registration devices? I would like only to pass e.g. gcm model like:

   `{
   "to": "registraionId",
    "data": {
      "title": "Some title",
       "message": "Some message"
      }
   }`

I saw that exists defined REST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223273.aspx but for me it not working, I suppose that flow should look like [make installation] -> [make registration] -> [send message] is it correct? I also tried to send message by visual studio and azure portal.

Is it possible to send messages without registration etc. ?

I will be very gratefull for any examples :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, of course  exists Rest api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608572.aspx which is used to sending direct messages to devices without registrations.